# How can I solve this using google bigQ

Tags: google-bigquery

An example problem to solve is to find the places in New York where it is least healthy to travel by a bicycle.

Combine

```
https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-public-data:openaq.global_air_quality and bigquery-public-data:new_york.citibike_stations
```

to find the top 5 bicycle rental stations in neighborhood of most air polluted NY areas.

What time of the year is worst to travel by bicycle due to heavy air pollution?

How to define neighborhood in terms of data that is present in the (both) sources?

Comment: show what you tried so far and what problem you've got

Comment: Add a reprex please. See a guideline here https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-whats-a-reproducible-example-reprex-and-how-do-i-do-one/5219

Comment: When asking a question involving code, you shouldn't just ask the community to provide you with that code. You must show what you have alredy tried and where you are stuck. See [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)